# I have merged but the master branch isn't changing

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches(**Master** and **Dev**). I did some things on the Dev branch, and attempted to merge them with the master branch.

```
git commit -am "Dev changes"
git push
git checkout master
git merge Dev
```

When I do this, I don't see **Master** change add the Dev files that I edited. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you on `Dev` when those commands start? Are the files you're changing actually tracked? Are you seeing any errors? What does `git log` show you on Dev and Master?

Comment: How are you looking for the changes? With git log, or by actually looking at the files, or with git diff?

Comment: In case you are looking for the changes in the remote master, you will not see them until you `git push` again.

Comment: One alternate option what I would suggest you is to use Rebase.. after checking out to master, use this command "git rebase -i Dev" . this lets you to use an interactive window where you can pick what all commits you need.

Comment: It was a git push problem. I never actually pushed the comments after the merge. In the future, I think I am going to use the rebasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to merge `master` changes to `dev` then you need to be inside `dev` branch

e.g

```
$ > git checkout dev
$dev > git commit -am "changes to dev"
$dev > git merge master
$dev > git log
```

you can also use `rebase` which will merge master into `dev` branch and then put your changes on top

e.g

```
$ master > git pull
$ master > git checkout dev
$ dev > git checkout -am "dev changes"
$ dev > git rebase master
$ dev > git log # should show your changes on top and master changes will be below your changes
```

But if your trying to merge `dev` changes to `master` then you need to be in `master` branch

e.g

```
$ dev > git commit -am "dev changes"
$ dev > git log # will show `dev changes` on top
$ dev > git checkout master
$ master > git merge dev
$ master > git log # now you should be able to see `dev` changes into `master`
```